# Custom exceptions handling - java Web Services

Tags: java, exception, soap, service, web

Its my first time posting here so please be patient and correct me whenever necessary...

I am building simple web service-based application using NetBeans with GlassFish. NetBeans does help a lot in terms of generating code for new web services and their operations, one thing drives me mad though - web service exception handling. Operation like:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "checkUserExist")
public String checkUserExist(@WebParam(name = "login") String login, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) throws LoginException {

    String auth_code = "";
    bk_end.Validate val = new bk_end.Validate();

    boolean isValidated = val.check(login, password);

    if(isValidated)
    {
        auth_code = val.return_AuthCode();
        bank_services.CustomerSerice.setAuth_Code(auth_code);
        return auth_code;
    }

    throw new LoginException("Something is wrong!");

}
```

and the exception class:

```
public class LoginException extends Exception
{
    String message;


    public LoginException(String message)
    {
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage()
    {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

throws a massive 
Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
plus tons of other exceptions..
I realise it is a very much so nooby question, but after many hours of trying various things I just do not know what tot do. 
I've read about the @WebFault thing but got no idea how to specify this correctly (attach my exception to a particular method..)

Please help, all ideas are more than welcome!

Exceptions that I'm getting:
Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details

```
Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:114)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletAdapter.java:1002)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(ServletAdapter.java:942) 
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:404)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:301)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: bank_services.LoginException_Exception: excepts.LoginException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:123)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
    at $Proxy383.checkUserExist(Unknown Source) ... 29 more
```

Comment: You said that when you throw LoginException, you get "tens of other exceptions but the one I want."  Could you please show us what exceptions are getting thrown instead?

Comment: true that, updated my question with required details !

Comment: anybody... ? I'm on it whole day already, there must be solution, its a beginners problem...

Comment: What exception do you "want"?  I don't understand what he problem is.  The cause of the `InvocationTargetException` should be the exception that caused the problem.

Comment: ok, my mistake above - not that I 'want' any exceptions, but what I would like to achieve is to be able (on the client side) to get the "Something is wrong" exception message when caught...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh ok.  You want to see the "Something is wrong" message.

So I think the ultimate problem here is that you are not using the standard `detailMessage` field in the `Throwable`.  If you just pass the message to the base class (`super(message);`) then I bet you would see the exception in the trace.  Did you try another `Exception` type such as just `Exception`?

You could also define the `LoginException.toString()` to be something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = getClass().getName();
    return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
}
```

Alternatively, you will need to do something like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof ServletException) {
        e = e.getCause();
    }
    if (e instanceof InvocationTargetException) {
        e = e.getCause();
    }
    if (e instanceof LoginException) {
        System.err.println("Login exception returned message: "
            + ((LoginException)e). getErrorMessage());
    } else {
        System.err.println("Exception returned message: " + e);
    }
}
```

But I think my recommendation is to use `super(message);` in your constructor.

Comment: As I already mentioned, my web service knowledge is very basic... What I'm trying to achieve: my client app sends two strings, web service operation checks them, if correct fine, if incorrect -> LoginException is thrown. If thrown on the server side (and worked properly) message ("Something is wrong") would be displayed to the user trying to log in... that is all...

Comment: And the client code has a copy of the class `LoginException` that is up-to-date?  You should add a `serialVersionUID` field to your exception and update it with a number.  Your client will throw an exception then if it doesn't have the right version of `LoginException`.

Comment: "Does the client have this class ?" - not sure if understand correctly - I'm using NetBeans to generate client-server related code...

Comment: Have you tried to just set the standard message?  How about changing your constructor to just call `super(message);`?  Can you print out the `exception.getCause().getCause().getErrorMessage()`?

Comment: My machine just died on me, on the top of everything else... will continue tomorrow - Gray -> thank you for your input mate !

Comment: Sure thing dude.  Best of luck.  I suspect that the message is in there just that it won't be in the stack trace unless you use the `super(message)` constructor.

Comment: +1 could be appreciated for the work.  You can accept if it helped later.

Comment: ok, finally got it right - Gray, your suggestions put me on the right track somehow :D rather than throwing LoginException, I've tried the Exception class (still not sure why custom exception did not work, but for now...), caught it on the client side and boom ! works ! cheers Gray !

Comment: Good.  I've just edited my answer.  I think the problem with your `LoginException` was your custom `message` field.  Did you try just doing `super(message);`?